# Missing class: androidx.paging.PositionalDataSource

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, androidx, android-r8

When processing files with R8 it cannot find `androidx.paging.PositionalDataSource`:

```
> Task :minifyReleaseWithR8
AGPBI: {"kind":"warning","text":"Missing class: androidx.paging.PositionalDataSource","sources":[{}],"tool":"R8"}
```

How to mute this warning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This comes from using Room without the Paging library:

```
implementation "androidx.paging:paging-common:3.0.0"
implementation "androidx.paging:paging-runtime:3.0.0"
```

While the same `-dontwarn` still works with R8:

```
-dontwarn androidx.paging.PositionalDataSource
```

Comment: Even as `-dontwarn` will get rid of the warning, it might make sense to try to track down if there is some missing dependency, either directly or indirectly.

Comment: @sgjesse I'd suspect this having to do with Room, without the Paging library. And something which one doesn't use obviously isn't a "missing dependency"; the shrinker might even remove the mere of it.